# "Make" missing in PATH for C/C++ in Eclipse

Tags: makefile

I just installed mingw with the compiler g++ and gcc, as followed by this youtube video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77xZOT3xer4

However, when I try to run the program, Eclipse says the following:

1. #include  is unresolved
2. using namespace std; std could not be resolved
3. cout and endl could not be resolved

Moreover, when I use build, I get the following errors:

```
"Program 'make' not found in PATH"
"Program 'g++' not found in PATH"
"Program 'gcc' not found in PATH"
```

Is there any way to solve the following problems?

Thank you!